# Algorithm to select an user from a database (For a online dual player game)

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm

If we suppose a online dual player game.
There is a table in a database (Users table) with columns **id**, **name**, **level**, **...**

When a user click a button it has to search for another user(*who also clicked the button to search*) with similar level and connect those users and start the game.

What I want is the algorithm to connect two players who are searching for a one when clicked a button.

It is easy if any can give a php code.

Comment: Of course it would be easy if others do your job for you, but that's not what SO is about. We're here to help you with problems in **your** code. Or as we like to say: SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service**. Now to give you a tip in the right direction: Have a database column int(1) named `searching` and set it to 1 on button click and back to 0 if no longer searching. Then simply have your system connect 2 players that both have 1 set in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you an idea. Share your thought if you find anything not fitting your request.

```
Player's table:
**id   name level status**
1      1    1     idle
2      2    3     playing
3      3    1     idle
4      4    3     playing
5      5    1     idle
```

step 1:
only idle player can search for player. say player:1 pressed search button.
then player:1's status will be searching. but it won't find anything as no body else is in search state and of the same state (searching).

send asynchronous request from the client that will periodically look for player via a php get/post request.

repeat this for any player who pressed search.

step 2: the asynchronous(eg. javascript ajax) request will request to php to look into database to match the criteria. when found, server(php end) will change state of both player 1 and 5 to playing and write a row in game table. and return game id as response to the javascript request.

```
game table:
**id playerOneId playerTwoId pLayerOneStatus  pLayerTwoStatus status**    
1    1            5          ready            ready          started
```

step-3:
the moment asynchronous request get game id as response it will redirect the player to game page. and set the player status to ready.

step-4: 
the moment both player are in ready state. the game will be started.

step-5: 
once the game end change player's table status to idle.
change game status to end

Let me know if it serves your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: **But the problem is if player 1,3 and 5 pressed the search button same time...then player 1's request choose player 5 and player 5's request choose player 3 and player 3's request choose 1 or 5**...same time...then it becomes a error...

Comment: please give me an answer for that

Comment: whenever the choose incident happens, you must look into game table if you are being assigned to anybody else.... if you are assigned you don't choose for the second player.... you just lock it, moreover PHP doesn't do threads. So it is supposed to be done in serial manner. Player 1 press search, first look into game table if you are being assigned to anybody else, it gets player , then you dont need to choose / write in game table again... just return the game id .... but if not found.... then create an instance in game table... and then return the id

Comment: ThankYou @Maverick_Mrt